# Is jquery not availble in integration test for rails 3.2 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

We use a fields_for and jquery to add a partial view on a form in rails 3.2 app. Here is the code:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
      new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
      fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
        render :partial => association.to_s, :locals => {:f => builder, :i_id => 0} 
      end
      link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{j fields}\")")
 end
```

In applicaton.js:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Whenever the 'Add Field' link is clicked, the partial view is rendered and a few input fields are added to the current form. The code works in execution without any problem. However in integration test (`capybara` & `launchy`), the `click_link('Add Field')` did not do anything and failed bringing up the partial. Is jquery not enabled in integration test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Capybara use `:rake_test` driver on all tests, which is fast but dosen't support JavaScript.

Since this test needs JavaScript, make sure you have turned JS driver on.

```
 describe "some feature", js: true do
   # test code
 end
```

This will use default JS driver Selenium.